# Tweepy showing less list members; is it a bug or limitation?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I have a list having 64 members in it, but when I try to extract members it only shows the first 20 members of the list. Is this an API limitation or a bug? Can I get the full list of members?

```
members = api.list_members(list_id = 1277128771720495104)
print(len(members)) 

ouput: 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GET lists/members](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/create-manage-lists/api-reference/get-lists-members), the Twitter API endpoint that [`API.list_members`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.10.0/api.html#API.list_members) uses, has a `count` parameter that:

> Specifies the number of results to return per page [. . .]. The default is 20, with a maximum of 5,000.

E.g.:

```
>>> members = api.list_members(list_id = 1277128771720495104)
>>> print(len(members))
20
>>> members = api.list_members(list_id = 1277128771720495104, count = 5000)
>>> print(len(members))
63
```